# Systematic way of calculating 3-point worldsheet amplitudes

Tags: string-theory, conformal-field-theory, correlation-functions

I'm looking for a systematic way of deriving the 3-point functions $\left< V_1(z_1, \bar{z}_1) V_2(z_2, \bar{z}_2)V_3(z_3, \bar{z}_3)\right>$ of the worldsheet CFT of a closed bosonic string.

Let me clarify a bit.

It is known that the physical states are a primary with weight $h = \bar{h} = 1$ subset of states that are generated by

$$ \varepsilon_{\mu_1 \dots \mu_n} :\partial^{\,k_1} \partial X^{\mu_1} \dots \partial^{\,k_n} \partial X^{\mu_n} \; e^{i p X}:. $$

Consider three such operators, each is specified by the polarization tensor $\varepsilon$ and the integers $\{k_i\}$ (both subject to the primality with $h=\bar{h}=1$ constraint).

I'm looking for a combinatoric relation

$$ \varepsilon, \{k_i\}, \varepsilon', \{k'_i\}, \varepsilon'', \{k''_i\} \rightarrow \left< V_{\varepsilon, \{k\}}(z_1, \bar{z}_1) V_{\varepsilon', \{k'\}}(z_2, \bar{z}_2) V_{\varepsilon'', \{k''\}}(z_3, \bar{z}_3)\right> $$

Because the 3-point function of primary fields is fixed by the $SL(2, \mathbb{C})$ symmetry up to the overall factor $C_{123}$, my question can be reformulated as:

I'm looking for a combinatoric relation

$$ C(\varepsilon, \{k_i\}; \varepsilon', \{k'_i\}; \varepsilon'', \{k''_i\}). $$

I understand in principle how such coefficients can be derived iteratively for small values of $k$. Here I'm looking for a systematic formula for the coefficient $C$.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94168/discussion-on-question-by-solenodon-paradoxus-systematic-way-of-calculating-3-po).